# Pop up wants “Default keyring” password blocks access to various objects on Ubuntu 22.04.1 after system upgrade

Tags: upgrade, password

This is a mystery password. Never set it and don’t know how.

Evidently I’ll need to correct this vis the command line. In the Gnome GUI interface all useful objects are evidently non functional without the password now.

Answer (score 2):

Just open "seahorse" app and right click on login keyring and select change password. If you dont know the old password delete or move the file `~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring` and create a new password keyring called login and set the password for it.